# Input sound has latency when the computer is connected to a speaker

Tags: microphone, macbook-pro, latency

I have a Mid-2014 MacBook Pro, and a very basic USB microphone.

When I connect the USB microphone and use a software like Line In or GarageBand, I can hear the input clearly from the MacBook's speakers with no latency.

When I plug in an external speaker to my MacBook though, the input from the microphone has a very noticeable latency.

What could be the cause of this? And is there anything I can do?

Comment: are the speakers connected through a line out jack, phones, usb or firewire?

Comment: @MichaelHansenBuur I tried connecting to speakers through line out, and also tried connecting to a TV through HDMI. There was latency in both those cases. When I take them off, and just get the sound from the onboard speakers though there is no noticeable latency. I'm feeling like this is more of a driver issue.

Comment: Sorry - it seems to be a pretty common problem - people seem to solve it using a good external sound interface. Source: http://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?threads/latency-on-a-macbook-pro.965034/

Answer (score -1):

cheap solution- listen on headphones for clarity and pitch tone etc record at the same time then playback without latency for the next track to be recorded at that time listen for a bit correct levels then take of audio line in to listen live to see how it fits.